# How to use methods of classes in Angular export function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'd like to use a method in a export function defined in a class file.

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
    return new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: AzureService.getConfiguration(), <-------- Compilation Error
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
            storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11. Remove this line to use Angular Universal
        }
    });
}

export class AzureModule { }
```

This is the Service Class

```
@Injectable()
export class AzureService {

    constructor(private identityManagerApiRestService: IdentityManagerApiRestService) { }

    getConfiguration(): BrowserAuthOptions {
        let options: BrowserAuthOptions;
        this.identityManagerApiRestService.getAuthenticationConfiguration().subscribe(response =>{
            options.clientId = response.authenticationConfiguration.clientId;
            options.authority = response.authenticationConfiguration.authority;
            options.redirectUri = response.authenticationConfiguration.redirectUri;
        });
        return options;
    }
}
```

How can I use AzureService.getConfiguration() method in the exported function method in the Module. I want this because the values are dynamic and they are obtained in a rest call.

Comment: Make getConfiguration() a static function.

Comment: I can't use the api in the constructor if I make it static.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const Service = new AzureService(IdentityManagerApiRestService)
let a = Service.getConfiguration()
```

Comment: Argument of type 'typeof IdentityManagerApiRestService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IdentityManagerApiRestService'.

Comment: your class exported with constructor. you should be first - create one with constructor, then use functions inside.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.